# Bind all concrete implementations by name in Ninject

Tags: c#, ninject, ninject-extensions

I have an interface `IAdapdor`, and several concrete implementations. Using Ninject 3.0, I bind them all by name:

```
IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();

kernel.Bind<IAdapdor>().To<Adaptor1>().Named("Adaptor1");
kernel.Bind<IAdapdor>().To<Adaptor2>().Named("Adaptor2");
...
```

How can I achieve this using [Ninject conventions extension](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions/wiki/Overview)?

To be more specific, I'm looking for something in the line:

```
kernel.Bind(x => x.FromThisAssembly()
                  .SelectAllClasses()
                  .InheritedFrom<IAdapdor>()
                  .BindByClassName()); // <-- BindByClassName() does not really exist
```

Comment: I am curious to hear what this convention is... because I don't see one. The Conventions extension doesn't solve everything... sometimes you need to explicitly bind things.

Comment: @Simon Whitehead - from what I understand, I should be able to do this in a single line with conventions. I'll edit the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the convention created bindings using the [`Configure` method](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions/wiki/Configuring-Bindings). So you can use that to register your bindings with `Named`:

```
kernel.Bind(x => x
    .FromThisAssembly()
    .SelectAllClasses().InheritedFrom<IAdapdor>()
    .BindAllInterfaces()
    .Configure((b, c) => b.Named(c.Name)));
```

Comment: ..does this take into account the numeric factor?

Comment: `c.Name` will get the name of your type so `Adaptor1` or `Adaptor2`. but you write there anything what you get the `"Adaptor1"` and `"Adaptor2"` based on the type beging registered

Comment: @nemesv, Right on! I knew this should be simple enough... Thanks!